# How Do I load a specific user content using a JWT token

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to set up a log in system in my app that loads user data from a mongodb using JWT tokens. I have the login part working so users can log in/out but now I need to fetch data specific to the user whom is logged in. This following code currently successfully logs the current JWT token. How would I go about updating this code so the details are loaded related to that user and not the position in the database:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const user = storedUser ? JSON.parse(storedUser) : null;
    console.log(user.token);
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/').then(function(response) {
      modelDetail = response.data;
      // console.log(modelDetail);
      setName(modelDetail[0].name);
      setDepth (modelDetail[0].Depth);
      setModelPath(modelDetail[0].Model);
    });
  }, []);
```

Any help appreciated.